# How to secure express api to allow only my angular app (domain)

Tags: angular, express, oauth-2.0, cors, jwt

I'm building an API in combination with an Angular App. Now I've implemented JWT to secure the api. Now we want also OAuth2 implemented that's also no issue.

But the thing is that the JWT only needs to be valid if the request is done from a certain domain. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by installing `cors` from npm with:

`npm install cors`

Then in your express app:

```
var cors = require('cors')

var corsOptions = {
origin: 'http://example.com',
optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) 
choke on 204 
}

app.get('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for only example.com.'})
})
```

Comment: I implemented it exactly like your example but it doesn't work. I'm using: typescript, [routing-controllers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/routing-controllers) maybe that's why it doesn't work?